# how can I make this code work-error message being received

Tags: ruby

Write a method that takes an integer `n` in; it should return
`n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...*2*1`. Assume `n >= 0`.
As a special case, `factorial(0) == 1`.
Difficulty: easy.

```
def factorial(n)
  a = 1
  store = []
  result = n - a

  while a <= (n-1) 
    j = n * result
    store << j
    a += 1
    store.each |j|
      add each j in array
    end
  end
```

Error:

> ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]
>       (repl):17: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
>       add each j in array
>               ^ (repl):32: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input

Comment: what is `add each j in array` ? Is this actual statement?

Comment: No, I won't. .....

Comment: I was trying to add up the values that will be shoveled to array store = [] because that will give me the answer. I am just curious how to go about printing out the sum of what is in store = []. Thank you for your help. Please keep going lol if possible

Comment: in addition, the first end goes with def, the second goes with while loop and the third goes with what?

Answer (score 0):

Reason for this error

```
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' add each j in array ^ (repl):32: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
```

is because you are missing `do` after `store.each`

```
def factorial(n)
  a = 1
  store = []
  result = n - a

  while a <= (n-1) 
    j = n * result
    store << j
    a += 1
    store.each do |j|
      # Not sure what are you trying to do here
      add each j in array
    end
  end
end
```

Also you were missing an `end` at the end.

NOTE: This code will not give the expected output still. Fix your logic first.